# Change color of progress bar in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

i am trying to change the color of horizontal progress bar but it is not changing. i did some googling and gone through some example given in ur site. But i am not getting success to change the color accurately. 
i used `progressBar.setProgressDrawable(Drawable d)` but it sets the background color of the whole progress bar view instead of setting the background color of only the bar itself.

Please, any body help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You Can create custom_progress.xml file in drawable folder -
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="2"
        android:thicknessRatio="6" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#c76a37" 
            android:endColor="#A4B4B9"
             />
    </shape>
</rotate> 

//And add below code to your layout file to create progress bar
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
        />
Hope this will help you.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am using this code in my project. I hope it works for you.

// Create ProgressBar in your layout file.

```
    <ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/yourid"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:progressDrawable="@drawable/slider"   
           />
```

// Create .xml file in your drawable folder with name slider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grey_bar_music"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/blue_bar_music" />
    </item>
</layer-list>

//grey_bar_music ->Background image name for  your progressbar.
//blue_bar_music->Progress bar change color using this image when it start from 0.
```